# Wiktionary claims 'dessen' cannot be followed by a noun in the genitive. Is this true?

Tags: grammaticality, declension, demonstrative-pronoun

In the [wiktionary article](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dessen#Usage_notes) of 'dessen', it says:

> Another common mistake is a double-genitive construction such as the
> following: Nach dem Tod seines Vaters wurde er Leiter dessen
> Betriebes. — “After the death of his father, he became the director of
> the latter’s company.” Since dessen/deren are substantival pronouns,
> not determiners, they can never have another genitive following them.
> The correct phrase reads: Nach dem Tod seines Vaters wurde er Leiter
> von dessen Betrieb. The mistake is from hypercorrection: the
> exaggerated desire to avoid the preposition von (“of”).

I am a native speaker and find this to be highly questionable. I am 100% sure that I am using such constructions, although I admit that it sometimes feels slightly odd, which led me to look this up in the first place. However, after searching my intuition, I firmly believe that this is actually 100% grammatical, notwithstanding what wiktionary claims.

My argument is this: Consider the following:

> Eines Mannes Betrieb ist sein Einkommen. (Nom)
>
> ...sah eines Mannes Betrieb. (Acc)
>
> ...gab eines Mannes Betrieb einen neuen Namen. (Dat)
>
> ...wurde eines Mannes Betriebes Leiter. (Gen)

surely, these are all grammatical, however weird. My point is, my native intuition tells me that 'eines Mannes' is not in agreement with Betrieb anyway, no matter the case. Is it not true, that I can replace 'eines Mannes' with 'dessen'?

> wurde dessen Betriebes Leiter
>
> = wurde Leiter dessen Betriebes

Why should the constituent 'dessen' now require agreement with the Betrieb, and why then should it not allow the Betrieb to stand in the genitive?

In short: Is 'Nach dem Tod seines Vaters wurde er Leiter dessen Betriebes' grammatical?

Comment: First of all, I would not take "Wik..." sources too seriously. They are crowd-sourced public opinion. Can be wrong any time. Second, with this question you leave the realm of grammar and enter the realm of style, so there is probably no absolute right or wrong, rather you will find more or less authoritative opinion. - I wonder what my prefered authoritative opinion-maker Ludwig Reiners ("DIe Stilfibel") would say.

Comment: As a native (German) speaker, why do you ask in English?

Comment: @RalfFriedl -  D'accord. Bonne question!

Comment: @RalfFriedl why not? This question might as well be interesting for the not-yet-perfectly-speaking-German community.

Comment: @infinitezero   Meine Haltung dazu war stets: Wer diese Site besucht, kann Deutsch oder lernt Deutsch; wenn er Deutsch lernt, ist er daran interessiert, deutsche Texte zu lesen - gerade auch dann, wenn er noch nicht in der Lage ist, solche Texte in der gleichen Perfektion zu produzieren. Bei der Französisch-Schwester-Site ärgere ich mich - der ich Französisch besser lernen möchte - über die vielen englischen Beiträge.

Comment: Nicht jeder, der Deutsch lernt, ist in der Lage einen solchen Text zu verstehen. Wie oft habe ich mich geärgert, dass ich interessante Erklärungen zu meiner Lernsprache in derselbigen Sprache nicht verstehen konnte, da diese mein Niveau übersteigen.

Comment: Es spricht ja desweiteren nichts gegen eine bilinguale Antwort in Deutsch und Englisch.

Comment: @RalfFriedl Ich hab auf Englisch gefragt, weil ich in anderen Sprach-SEs manchmal genervt davon war, wenn das Verstehen des Threads für mich als Lernenden schwerer zu verstehen war als das eigentliche Thema des Threads. Ich habe dann oft das Gefühl, dass ich, wenn ich in der Lage wäre den Thread zu verstehen, die Antwort auf die Frage eh schon nicht mehr bräuchte. In dem Fall hier ist es natürlich offensichtlich nicht so, aber ich habe nicht darüber nachgedacht.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Begründung ist in der Tat nicht eben erhellend, im Ergebnis ist die Aussage aber letztlich plausibel. Zunächst einmal ist *dessen* zumindest nach dem Verständnis der deutschen Grammatik auch eine Art Determinativum (die IDS-Grammatik spricht allgemein von einem Ausdruck der Objektdeixis, andere von einem deiktischen Determinativ). Das "*dessen*-Unbehagen" lässt sich durch solche terminologisch immer etwas heiklen Abgrenzungen (Determinativ vs. Pronomen) jedenfalls nicht überzeugend erklären.

Beginnen wir mit einem weiteren Beispiel (aus Zifonun 2003: 18):

> Die DRK-Kreisvorsitzende Diemut Theato dankte Alfred Nennstiel im
>   Beisein dessen Nachfolgers Thomas Lochner (...) (Rhein-Neckar-Zeitung,
>   15.01.2003)

Der Grund, warum das eventuell ungrammatisch ist, liegt in einer Eigenart des deutschen Genitivs. Aus der agrammatischen Natur von **der Einkauf Stahls* und dergleichen folgert man allgemeiner:

- (Müller 2002:) G-PRÜF (Genitivüberprüfung): Morphologischer Genitiv auf N[omina] muss per Spezifikator-Kopf-Kongruenz abgeglichen werden.
- (Zifonun 2003:) Der Genitiv eines appellativischen Substantivs kann nur in einer Nominalgruppe mit kongruierendem Begleiter erscheinen.
- (Gallmann in Duden-Grammatik 2016:) Genitivregel: Eine Nominalphrase kann nur dann im Genitiv stehen, wenn sie (i) mindestens ein adjektivisch flektiertes Wort und (ii) mindestens ein Wort mit *s-* oder *r*-Endung enthält.

Beobachtung: Offenbar kongruiert *dessen* in Ihrem Beispiel

> Nach dem Tod seines Vaters wurde er Leiter dessen Betriebes.

nicht mit *Betrieb*. Vergleiche

> Nach dem Tod seines Vaters wurde er Leiter *deren Werkstatt.

(Hingegen: *Nach dem Tod seines Vaters wurde er Leiter eine**s**/seine**s** Betriebes.* vs. *Nach dem Tod seines Vaters wurde er Leiter eine**r**/seine**r** Werkstatt.*)

Der Genitiv *Betriebes* steht mithin -- in Ermangelung eines kongruierenden Begleiters -- im Sinne der angeführten Regeln unbegleitet, sodass der Fall -- durch die Brille der oben genannten Regeln betrachtet -- im Grunde ebenso liegt wie in **Er wurde Leiter Betriebes*. Dieses Konstruktionsproblem fällt in Ihrem Beispiel und dem der Rhein-Neckar-Zeitung wohl deshalb nicht sofort auf, weil *Vater* und *Betrieb* bzw. *Alfred Nennstiel* und *Nachfolger* jeweils beide Maskulina sind, sodass man geneigt sein mag, *dessen* gedanklich quasi in einer Doppelrolle zu interpretieren.

Der präsentierte Fall ist freilich ein Spezialfall. Die Konstellation fällt möglicherweise auch durch das Raster anderer Varianten der "Genitivregel", wie man sie in geeigneter Form vereinzelt durchaus auch in Schul- und Fremdsprachengrammatiken findet. Umgekehrt mag man einwenden, dass manchen Grammatikern diverse Varianten der "Genitivregel" zu restriktiv sind (vgl. Wiese 2017: 1315). Ich denke aber persönlich nicht, dass jemand Ihre Konstruktion bei näherer Betrachtung tatsächlich für grammatisch hielte. (Wohlgemerkt: Bei näherer Betrachtung. Die erste Intuition steht auf einem anderen Blatt. Auf mich wirkte Ihr Beispiel bei der ersten Lektüre zum Beispiel zwar unrund, aber keineswegs eindeutig falsch.) Soweit diese irgendwelche anderen "Genitivtests" passiert, ist das mutmaßlich eher einer terminologischen Vereinfachung in der Formulierung der Tests geschuldet (es ist schon ungewöhnlich, dass man in der genitivischen Nominalphrase einen flektierten "Begleiter" hat, der nicht mit dem Kopfnomen kongruiert ...). Wenn man näher schaut, sieht man aber m.E. ganz gut, dass hier "getrickst" wird, also eine Konstruktion zum Einsatz kommt, deren scheinbare Grammatikalität durch geeignete Austauschübungen sofort in sich zusammenfällt. Zusätzlich zu der oben durchgeführten können Sie übrigens auch einmal schauen, was passiert, wenn Sie den *Vater* durch die *Mutter* ersetzen. Dort lässt sich wiederum beobachten, dass ausschließlich im Fall zufälliger Genusidentität mit dem späteren Nomen eine nicht offensichtlich ungrammatische Konstruktion entsteht: *?Nach dem Tod seiner Mutter wurde er Leiter deren Werkstatt.* Das ist sprachlich "unlogisch".

<sub>L: P Gallmann, *Die flektierbaren Wortarten*, in: *Duden: Die Grammatik*, 9. Aufl. 2016; G Müller, *Syntaktisch determinierter Kasuswegfall in der deutschen
NP*, in: *LB* 189, 89, hier zit. nach dem Postprint unter https://home.uni-leipzig.de/muellerg/mu3.pdf; B Wiese, *Flexive in Phrasen*, in: Gunkel et al, *Grammatik des Deutschen im europäischen Vergleich: Das Nominal*, Teilbd. 2, 2017; G Zifonun, *Was geschieht, wenn* dessen *einen Genitiv trifft?*, in: *Sprachreport*, 3/2003, 18–22, https://pub.ids-mannheim.de//laufend/sprachreport/pdf/sr03-3b.pdf.</sub>

Comment: Kleiner Hinweis: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1048/25241

Comment: "Kleiner Hinweis: german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1048/25241" -> Ja, dann löschen wir die Antwort eben wieder. Das macht wirklich keinen Spaß hier. Einem deutschen Muttersprachler auf Deutsch antworten? Ungeheuerlich. Gutes Gelingen weiterhin.

Comment: Ich stelle fest, dass meine (gelöschte) Antwort wiederhergestellt wurde; meine damals bereits vorbereiteten Verbesserungen habe ich nun noch vorgenommen. Wenn ihr die Dauerkritik an der vermeintlich "falschen" Sprache von Antworten beibehalten wollt, macht es. Ich habe darauf keine Lust mehr. Ich bin/war lange genug hier, um zu wissen, dass Antworten in der Sprache der Frage *empfohlen* werden ("should", nicht "must"). Warum jedes Mal Antwortende kritisiert werden müssen, wenn sie davon abweichen, weiß ich nicht. Und wenn ich es (durch Löschung) korrigieren will, ist es auch nicht recht ...

Comment: Es ist erstaunlich, welch ein Drama Sie aus den zwei wohlgemeinten Worten „Kleiner Hinweis“ machen, zumal sie mit Kritik (wenn Sie den Hinweis so nennen wollen) rechnen müssten, wenn Sie bewusst und grundlos von der üblichen Vorgehensweise abweichen.
PS: Rein inhaltlich finde ich Ihre Antwort gut.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Es geht nicht um diese eine Äußerung. Jedes Mal wird man hier kritisiert, wenn man in der "falschen" Sprache fragt/antwortet. Damit nervt man andere Menschen auf Dauer eben (was wohl auch die Absicht ist). Das ist kein Vorwurf an Sie persönlich, sondern an die hiesige Kultur. Übrigens: Ja, was ist wohl der Grund für die deutsche Antwort? Vielleicht, dass der Fragesteller deutscher Muttersprachler ist und ich für die Antwort mindestens zehn Minuten länger benötigt hätte, wenn ich sie auf Englisch verfasst hätte (auch wegen der Zitate)?

Comment: "Nach dem Tod seiner Mutter wurde er Leiter deren Werkstatt"
Auch diesen empfinde ich ehrlichgesagt nicht als falsch, und kann das Zusammenfallen der Grammatikalität durch einen solchen Austausch nicht direkt nachvollziehen, womit ich aber zugegebenermaßen von der Mehrheit abweichen könnte. Den zitierten Satz der Rhein-Necker-Zeitung würde ich persönlich als absolut unauffällig einschätzen, was mich ebenfalls stutzig macht. Die Verwendung scheint so häufig zu sein, dass sie, wie der anderen Antwort zu entnehmen, sogar als Beispiel im Dudeneintrag 'dessen' dient.

Comment: Ohne die generelle Validität dieser linguistischen Veröffentlichungen in Frage stellen zu wollen, frage ich mich deshalb, ob nicht eine terminologische Vereinfachung oder generell ein zu simpel gefasstes 'Modell' zum *Nicht
bestehen dieser Tests führt. Letztlich landet man hier vielleicht wieder bei einer generellen Debatte darüber, welches Level von Akzeptanz - gerade der Duden-Eintrag dürfte eine relativ große Akzeptanz bezeugen - in der Sprecherschaft oder welche Kompatibilität mit etablierten ling. Theorien der Sprache überhaupt ein hinreichendes Kriterium für Grammatikalität darstellt.

Comment: @johnl Ich denke mal, man kann sagen, es ist nach einigen Ansichten nicht grammatisch, wird allerdings trotzdem häufig genug verwendet, um für viele Mutterspracher als unauffällig empfunden zu werden, und kann daher von einem deskriptivistischen Standpunkt zumindest bedingt als grammatisch bezeichnet werden.

Comment: @JMC Ja, eben, _Nach dem Tod seiner Mutter wurde er Leiter deren Werkstatt_ klingt nicht so schlecht, _Nach dem Tod seiner Mutter wurde er Leiter deren Architekturbüros_ ist aber m.E. nicht akzeptabel. Auch: _*Ich habe gestern Herbert und die Katze dessen Tochter gesehen. *Ich habe gestern Mathilda und den Hund deren Vaters gesehen. *Ich habe gestern Klaus und Katja und den Bruder deren Freundin gesehen._ Wenn Sie das alles absolut unauffällig finden, dann mag (zumindest in Ihrer Wahrnehmung) alles regelgerecht vor sich gehen und die Kongruenz einfordernde Literatur schlicht auf Abwegen sein.

Comment: Wenn Sie jedoch auch nur bei einem dieser Beispiele zucken, dann sollten Sie sich genauer überlegen, was hier passiert. Jedenfalls fehlt dann einstweilen eine "Gegenregel". Damit beginnen viele linguistischen Forschungsprojekte ... Manchmal steht an deren Ende aber auch die Erkenntnis, dass Sprecher eine eigentlich akzeptierte Regeln überschreiten, wenn ein bestimmter Kontext aus irgendwelchen Gründen zum Regelübertritt "einlädt". So etwas spricht dann eher nicht gegen die Regel.

Comment: Das muss man letztlich ergebnisoffen angehen. Einerseits ist nicht alles, was wir als Sprecher produzieren, grammatisch (auch nicht, wenn viele Sprecher es tun); andererseits müssen Linguisten natürlich auch evaluieren, ob das, was sie als Regeln identifiziert zu haben glauben, wirklich mit der Realität übereinstimmt. Dieser Präskriptiv-/Deskriptiv-Konflikt, wie er Sprachwissenschaftlern so gerne nachgesagt wird, hat heute ja auch wenig mit der Praxis zu tun. (** linguistischen > linguistische)

Answer (score 0):

## Fix the Wiktionary!

Allow the double-genitive for father's firm's manager,

*…wurde er…*

- *Leiter des Betriebes seines Vaters*
- *Leiter seines Vaters Betriebes*
- *Leiter dessen Betriebes*
- *Leiter seines Betriebes*

all are perfectly fine and dandy!

Compare the plural:

- *Leiter der Betriebe seiner Eltern*
- *Leiter seiner Eltern Betriebe*
- *Leiter derer Betriebe*
- *Leiter ihrer Betriebe*

## Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod!

- *Leiter **von** [wem/was:] dessen/deren Betrieb*

## Dessen/deren officially inflect weakly

- *Leiter von dessem/derem Betrieb*

can be heard that strongly inflected but according to https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dessem and https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/derem contradict standard grammars who prefer *dessen/deren* weakly uninflected with no further case suffices, namely there:

- <s>*mit dessem/derem ältesten Sohn*</s>
- *mit dessen/deren ältestem Sohn*

*Dessen* without dative *-m* works for similar reasons as *dessen* without further genitive *-s*.

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dessen blesses

- *die Ankunft meines Bruders und dessen Verlobter*

in which i would trade that strong genitive noted in https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verlobte for the weak genitive from https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Verlobte when interchanging a stronger pronoun in front of the verb turned past participle adjective turned noun:

- *die Ankunft meines Bruders und seiner Verlobten*

The canoo http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-der-die-das.html?MenuId=Word4240&lang=en also does without *dessem* inflection in favor of

- *Otto und Peter trafen zusammen mit dessen Freund (= Peters Freund) ein.*

Comment: Those are not fine. all examples for the singular inflect with -s, but *dessen* doesn't. why? per chance because it's wrong. We want an accademic source, duden or cannoo for example. I'm not quick to call anything wrong, but it's not correct just because it sounds right to you, and in fact it sounds odd to me, now.

Comment: @Roman Czyborra I really like this answer because of the Duden and canoonet references. However grammatical it might be, I am at least not alone in using and encountering it frequently.